# Solving Oblique Boundary value problem using Neumann Boundary Condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{2}a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial^{2}u }{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}+ b_{i}(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}+ c(x)u=\lambda u ~~~in ~~\Omega\\
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 ~~on ~~\partial\Omega
\end{align*}
The solution for the above equation is known when $\Omega$ is smooth. Its not clear to me how to prove the similar result when the boundary condition becomes oblique (we  can assume that oblique direction is smooth).

Comment: You will find a brief discussion of this problem, with some references, at the Springer [EoM](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Differential_equation,_partial,_oblique_derivatives&oldid=33911).

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. But here I am asking about is it possible to do this problem via coordinate transformation, i.e., is it possible to transform the oblique boundary value problem to Neumann boundary value problem.

Comment: In the usual definition of Neumann BVP, the derivative is taken in the direction orthogonal to the boundary, where orthogonality is measured with respect to the $a_{ij}(x)$ metric. This notion of orthogonality is invariant under coordinate transformations (the $a_{ij}(x)$ coefficients of the equation also transform under coordinate transformations). In this sense, a general oblique BVP cannot be transformed to a Neumann BVP.